# how would i use error handling to allow me this program to accept both strings and integers

Tags: python

Here is the code :

```
PI = 3.14
radius = float(input('Please Enter the Radius of a Sphere: '))

sa = 4 * PI * radius * radius
Volume = (4 / 3) * PI * radius ** 3

print("\n The Surface area of a Sphere = %.2f" %sa)
print("\n The Volume of a Sphere = %.2f" %Volume)
```

Its says above `please enter the radius of a sphere`. How could I make it not error code if I enter a string because when I do it says this :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:/Gary/Test2/Euan_4.py", line 2, in <module>
    radius = float(input('Please Enter the Radius of a Sphere: '))
ValueError: could not convert string to float: 'rtt'
```

How could this be fixed.

Comment: depends on what you are trying, do you want error checking? or do you assume user will always input it in the right format

Comment: See the python documentation about exception handling https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/errors.html#handling-exceptions

Comment: @pyjg error checking is what im trying to go

Comment: @eunason see my answer :)

Answer (score 0):

```
def take_input():
  try:
    radius = float(input('Please Enter the Radius of a Sphere: '))
    return radius
  except:
    print('please enter a float')
    return take_input()




radius = take_input()
```

this will retry till user enters the right input.

Comment: have u got a remedy for when i enter a 'y' it would error straight away @pyjg could u help me fix this

Comment: what do you mean? if you enter 'y' and hit return it will show the error and ask for input again

Comment: no it wont ask for input itll just say 'Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:/Gary/Test2/Euan_4.py", line 2, in <module>
    radius = float(input('Please Enter the Radius of a Sphere: '))
ValueError: could not convert string to float: 'y' @pyjg like i want it to , if i enter a string , to print 'thats a string try again ' and not error

Comment: I do not see how that is happening. https://repl.it/K3wL check this link

Answer (score 0):

You could use `try.. except`

```
try: 
    PI = 3.14
    radius = float(input('Please Enter the Radius of a Sphere: '))

    sa = 4 * PI * radius * radius
    Volume = (4 / 3) * PI * radius ** 3

    print("\n The Surface area of a Sphere = %.2f" %sa)
    print("\n The Volume of a Sphere = %.2f" %Volume)
except Exception as e:
    print("error : " +str(e))
    print("make sure to provide an float as input")
```

Here's the output when testing with a number:

```
Please Enter the Radius of a Sphere: 111

 The Surface area of a Sphere = 154751.76

 The Volume of a Sphere = 4294361.34
```

Here's the output when testing with a string:

```
Please Enter the Radius of a Sphere: rtt
error : name 'rtt' is not defined
make sure to provide an float as input
```

Comment: i use this and its got red lines next to 'except Exception as e:
    print("eorr : " +str(e))' and ' PI = 3.14
    radius' y is this @MedAli

Comment: @eunason I tried it on my system, I am editing the answer to share what I am getting as ouput. Could you share you python version ?